# How do I add a linebreak at the end of a string in text files?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I tried doing this:

```
with open("contactbook.txt","a") as f:
     f.write("hello\n")
```

But it gets printed as:

```
'hello\n'
```

My code to read the file:

```
with open("contactbook.txt","r") as f:
     lines = sorted(f.readlines())
     print(lines)
```

EDIT:

I tried to check the text file and there \n really was interpreted as a linebreak!

But in python's shell it's still showing as \n

What am I doing wrong? Is it because of how I print it?

Comment: What program do you use to check how it gets printed?

Comment: Hey this is perfectly working and nothing wrong, delete file and run again.it may be due to append mode you may be seeing old data again.

Comment: This code should run as desired. What OS are you working at? What IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: @VigneshRajendran Hi! I already did, but it's still getting printed as \n :(

Comment: @AlbertAlberto Windows 10, python 3.8.3

Comment: @zabop python itself

Comment: what is your default text editor?

Comment: @VigneshRajendran notepad

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved it hehe the problem was with the way I print it out, the code for the line break was correct just like you guys said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being written out fine.

The problem is that when you read the file back in, you print out the whole `lines` list in a single `print(lines)` statement; this will give you a form suitable for debugging, not really for display to the end-user, including writing out control characters as `\n` and so on.

If you check the file in any other way, you'll be able to confirm that it has the content that you want.

Comment: Ohhh so you mean I should use loops to print it?

Comment: Yeah. Or whatever other processing you need to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there are other people like me who gets the same problem...

The problem with my code before is the way I print it out so by changing how I read/print it to:

```
with open('contactbook.txt', 'r') as f:
     for lines in sorted(f):
          print(lines, end='')
```

It now works!

sabik's answer helped me realized this! :)

Comment: You could also use `print(''.join(lines))` without the loop.